# Why does this infinitive have perfect tense?

Tags: tense, perfect-constructions

> She [my mother] quadrupled her already fabulous record and she was
>   awarded the fairest prize of all - a ride in an army airplane.
>   Oh, we were proud kids! Even vicariously this was an eminence we could
>   hardly stand. But my poor mother - I must tell you that there are
>   certain things in the existence of which my mother did not believe,
>   against any possible evidence to the contrary. One was a bad Hamilton
>   and another was the airplane. The fact that she had seen them didn’t
>   make her believe in them one bit more.
>  In the light of what she
>   did I have tried to imagine how she felt. Her soul must have crawled
>   with horror, for how can you fly in something that does not exist? As
>   a punishment the ride would have been cruel and unusual, but it was a
>   prize, a gift, an honor, and an eminence. She must have looked into
>   our eyes and seen the shining idolatry there and understood that she
>   was trapped. **Not to have gone** would have let her family down. She
>   was surrounded, and there was no honorable way out save death. Once
>   she had decided to go up in the nonexistent thing she seemed to have
>   had no idea whatever that she would survive it. (John Steinbeck, East
>   of Eden)

I can see the subjunctive mood, but why does the infinitive have perfect tense? Being the subject in the sentence, it seems to have simple tense – not to go.

Comment: I would say *perfect* and *simple* are aspects, not tenses.

Comment: @snailboat I would say they're *constructions* elicited by various combinations of tense, aspect, and mood. For instance, English 'simple past' may express either perfective aspect or a non-past hypothetical mood, while 'perfect' constructions usually express stative aspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very subtle effect. The key is the following construction with *have*: *it would have let her family down.*

Let's put ourselves in the mother's position. At the moment the choice presents itself, she might think, first:

> "Not to go **will** let my family down." ... *that is*, "If I **do not go** it **will let** my family down."

Translate that into the narrative past and you get:

> Not to go **would** let her family down. ... If she **did not go** it **would let** her family down.

But as Steinbeck has characterized the mother, this is not a choice open to her: *She was trapped ... She was surrounded, and there was no honorable way out.* It is in fact a classic *irrealis*, a counterfactual. That is expressed in the present with a past form:

> "If I **did not go** it **would let** my family down."

Past-in-past is expressed with the past perfect:

> If she **had not gone** it **would have let** her family down.  > Not to **have gone**  **would have let** her family down.